# Code getting into infinite loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

My code is getting into infinite loop even if I input "yes" or "yeah".

Below is my code:

```
var answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");   
while(answer != "yes" || answer != "yeah" ){
    var answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");    
}    
alert("YAY! We made it!!");
```

Comment: What is your quesion?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: The answer will _always_ be either not “yes” or not “yeah”. You want `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: When `answer == "yes"` then it's not equal to `"yeah"`. When `answer == "yeah"` then it's not equal to `"yes"`

Comment: Suppose you type `"yes"`. Then your condition is "if false or true try again". If you type `yeah`, it's "if true or false try again". If you type anything else, it's "if true or true try again". There is no scenario in which your code doesn't try again.

Comment: Also `var answer` is declared twice. It would be an issue if it was `let`, because you would actually have two `answer` variables in two different scopes

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! Now I have got it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `||` to `&&`.

You are asking: If your answer is not "yes" or it is not "yeah". If you answer with "yes", the answer is not "yeah". If you answer with "yeah" your answer is not "yes". That's why you haven an infinite loop.

Check out [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more details. Negotiation of `!(answer == "yes" || answer == "yeah")`  results also in changing the or operator.

```js
var answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");

while(answer != "yes" && answer != "yeah" ){
    answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");    
}

alert("YAY! We made it!!");
```

Comment: No need to define answer twice.

Comment: @SagiRika First, if you check the times, I *started* my answer before the answer was in the comments. Second check out [SO Meta: Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17479): "Answers should be answers". That is kind of obvious though... You cannot mark comments as the right answer.

Comment: I meant the fact that you use `var answer` twice, but I can see you editted that now.

Comment: @SagiRika Oh damn. I am very sorry for that. I felt a little bit offended. I just copied the question code. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't redefine `answer` (remove `var` from the loop). Secondly, think about the three possible cases your loop has:

```
answer = "yes"  ->  (answer != "yes") is false, (answer != "yeah") is true. The loop continues.
answer = "yes"  ->  (answer != "yes") is true, (answer != "yeah") is false. The loop continues.
answer = "anything else"  ->  (answer != "yes") is true, (answer != "yeah") is true. The loop continues.
```

Using a logical AND `&&` operator should resolve your issue:

```js
var answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");
while (answer != "yes" && answer != "yeah") {
  answer = prompt("Are we there yet?");
}
alert("YAY! We made it!!");
```